# Is there a method in GCP to update the encryption of a storage bucket using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to update the kms-key of a cloud storage bucket using get and put REST api's. I am wondering if i can use any of the patch or update methods in this doc - https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/storage/buckets.html  ??

Comment: [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) for [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) for [Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/#buckets) describes [`patch`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/patch) and lists [`encryption`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/patch#encryption) as writable. Use this documentation to guide your use of the Python method. Please be careful updating this value.

Comment: @gcp_user, does the previous comment answer your question? If so, please post it as an answer so that it will benefit other community members who have similar questions to yours.

Comment: I was using the patch method and tried to update the encryption value , I added a print statement before and after and i see the value is resolving to correct key, but when i go to console, it still has the old value. Any idea?

Comment: Before: 
{'kind': 'storage#bucket', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket-name', 'id': 'bucket-name', 'name': 'bucket-name', 'projectNumber': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'metageneration': '11', 'location': 'US-EAST1', 'storageClass': 'STANDARD', 'etag': 'CAs=', 'defaultEventBasedHold': False, 'encryption': {'defaultKmsKeyName': 'projects/xxxxxxxxxxxx/locations/us-east1/keyRings/sample-keyring/cryptoKeys/sample-key'}

Comment: After:    
{'kind': 'storage#bucket', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket-name', 'id': 'bucket-name', 'name': 'bucket-name', 'projectNumber': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'metageneration': '11', 'location': 'US-EAST1', 'storageClass': 'STANDARD', 'etag': 'CAs=', 'defaultEventBasedHold': False, 'timeCreated': '2022-05-06T10:41:26.455Z', 'updated': '2022-07-28T15:27:23.405Z', 'encryption': {'defaultKmsKeyName': 'projects/xxxxxxxxxxxx/locations/us-east1/keyRings/sample-keyring-test/cryptoKeys/sample-key-test'}

Answer (score 0):

As per @DazWilkin's comment:

> [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) for [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) for [Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/#buckets) describes [`patch`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/patch) and lists [`encryption`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/patch#encryption) as writable.

Documentations provided above would be used for your Python method. Values should be correct to avoid errors.